# Aligning input field with selection field

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm building a web application using html, java, javascript and css with bootstrap. Here is one section of that application which gives me troubles:

[image]

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to  move this input field bellow the first row to be just bellow the first selection field. Something like this:

[image]

By the way new rows are added dinamically when user clicks on + button. And now here is that section written in html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-5 formular-element-width-fix">
        <label class="control-label formular-element-label" for="element<%=elementNumber%>">Element
            <%=elementNumber %>:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control width100" id="element<%=elementNumber%>" name="element<%=elementNumber%>" placeholder="Enter a label">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
        <select class="form-control width100" onchange="changeValidations(this); showRadioLabels(this)">
            <option value="Textbox" selected>Textbox</option>
            <option value="Checkbox">Checkbox</option>
            <option value="Radio buttons">Radio buttons</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-1 radio-number-hide">
        <select class="form-control width100" onchange="changeRadioLabels(this)">
            <option value="1" selected>1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
        <select class="form-control width100">
            <option value="None" selected>None</option>
            <option value="Mandatory">Mandatory</option>
            <option value="Numeric">Numeric</option>
            <option value="Email">Email</option>
            <option value="Date">Date</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-add-element" onclick="addElement()">&#43;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-5 formular-element-width-fix radio-input radio-input-hidden">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control width100" id="new-element-input" name="new-element-input" placeholder="Enter a label">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, bootstrap takes 12 columns in one row, and if you try to use more than 12 columns, it automatically places the extra content in next row. Below is the snippet to achieve the result:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-5 formular-element-width-fix">
        <label class="control-label formular-element-label" for="element<%=elementNumber%>">Element
            <%=elementNumber %>:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control width100" id="element<%=elementNumber%>" name="element<%=elementNumber%>" placeholder="Enter a label">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
        <select class="form-control width100" onchange="changeValidations(this); showRadioLabels(this)">
            <option value="Textbox" selected>Textbox</option>
            <option value="Checkbox">Checkbox</option>
            <option value="Radio buttons">Radio buttons</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-1 radio-number-hide">
        <select class="form-control width100" onchange="changeRadioLabels(this)">
            <option value="1" selected>1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
        <select class="form-control width100">
            <option value="None" selected>None</option>
            <option value="Mandatory">Mandatory</option>
            <option value="Numeric">Numeric</option>
            <option value="Email">Email</option>
            <option value="Date">Date</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <!--here completing 12 columns of first row-->
    <div class="col-xs-2 form-group btn-group"> 
        <button class="btn btn-add-element" onclick="addElement()">&#43;</button>
    </div>
   <!--for next row, leave first 5 columns blank, which correspond to label and 
   textfield, Added css here-->
    <div class="form-group col-xs-5 formular-element-width-fix"> </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-5 formular-element-width-fix radio-input radio-input-hidden">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control width100" id="new-element-input" name="new-element-input" placeholder="Enter a label">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Ok, this is a good answer, but I tried that. When I insert tenth element for example I get a situation like this: https://ibb.co/k8vCPq

Comment: I edited the code snippet to add css classes formular-element-width-fix and form-group on second row's first 5 columns as well to exactly mimic top row. Please let me know, if this worked :)

Comment: In my case the answer was to actually remove formular-element-width-fix class, and now it works. Thank you for pointing me to this answer again, because i dissmissed it earlier :-)